# Make matching example from sed manual working

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I found an example in `info sed` stating the following:

```
'^\(.*\)\n\1$'
                   This matches a string consisting of two equal substrings separated
                   by a newline.
```

Trying to implement it in this ways didn't 
return any matching lines:

```
echo -e "test\ntest" | sed -n '/^\(.*\)\n\1$/p'
echo -e "test\ntest" | sed -n 's/^\(.*\)\n\1$/\0/p'
```

sed version I use is 4.2.2.

Please suggest the way this example can be tested.

Comment: Sed only reads a line at a time, use `echo -e "test\ntest" | sed -n 'N;/^\(.*\)\n\1$/p'` to get your desired result.

Comment: What will cause usage of 'N'?

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed and bash);

```
<<<$'test\ntest' sed -En 'N;s/^(.*)\n\1$/\1 == \1/p;s/^(.*)\n(.*)$/\1 != \2/p'
```

Append the second line of the input to the first and if the two lines are the same, replace them by `line1 == line2` otherwise replace them by `line1 != line2`.

N.B. That both substitutions are trying to match at least a newline and if the first substitution succeeds the second can not. Likewise, if the first substitution never happened the second must.

Answer (score 0):

To make an example work, I will have to use **N** that will read one more line in a pattern space and allow **\n** to be matched.